# Model of supply and demand

Tags: python

In a model of supply and demand,

the supply is:

```
Qs = P**a + P + 1
```

And the demand is:

```
Qd = 1/(0.5*P**2 + P)
```

I want to draw a sample of `1000` values for a assuming that a is a random variable which is uniformly distributed within interval `[0.2,2.0]`.
Then I want to solve the equilibrium price for each by numerically finding the root of the excess demand function.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

a= np.linspace(0.2,2.0, num=1000)
z = 0.5  
    
    excess_demand = lambda W: 1/(z*P**2 +P)  - (P**(a) +P + 1)
    
    W, res = optimize.brentq(excess_demand, 1e-8, 1000.0, full_output=True)
    assert res.converged == True
    print(res)
    print(W)
```

It appears me an error in the a in the 6th rows? Can you tell me why?

This is the output:

```
    excess_demand = lambda W: 1/(z*P**2 +P)  - (P**(b) +P + 1)
                                                   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I wrote a similar code that works:

```
from scipy import optimize

def main():
    """
    find market-clearing price in a one period macro model 
    
    Goods supply (Cobb-Douglas production function z*K**theta*L**(1-theta)): 
            z*K*((1-theta)*z/W)**((1-theta)/theta) 
    Private goods demand (quasi-linear utility function ln(c) + alpha*l): 
            W/alpha 
    Government budget balanced:  G = T       
    """
    alpha, theta, G, K, z = 1.0, 0.3, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0  #parameters
    
    excess_demand = lambda W: W/alpha + G  - z*K*((1.0-theta)*z/W)**((1.0-theta)/theta)
    
    W, res = optimize.brentq(excess_demand, 1e-8, 1000.0, full_output=True)
    assert res.converged == True
    print(res)
    print(W)
```

And the output is:

```
      converged: True
           flag: 'converged'
 function_calls: 21
     iterations: 20
           root: 0.5760098707985172
0.5760098707985172
```

Comment: what is the error? please give the full output so we know how to help

Comment: Your code is indented even though there's no block (e.g. `if`, `for`) requiring to do so.

Comment: Even if you indent your code correctly, `P` seems not to be defined.

Comment: How can I define P? It is just the price, it is what I want to find

Comment: Do you mean that I need to use if? @white

Comment: Maybe `W` is `P`. In this case, change `lambda W:` to `lambda P:`

Comment: I checked the documentation for `scipy.optimize.brentq`. First parameter needs to be a function returning a single numeral value, so lamda could work here. The function does in fact solve for P. The problem I'm currently having when trying to get your code to work is that f(a) and f(b) need to have different signs (whereas `a` and `b` are the 2nd and 3rd parameter in `brentq()`)

Comment: It doesn't work. @Corralien

Comment: Yes, probably the problem is in brentq(), but I don't understand what is wrong. @white

Answer (score 0):

Since Brent’s method needs to have f(a) and f(b) return values with different signs and your excess-function does not fullfull this requirements, it won't work that way. Therefore I suggest Newton's method, with which I managed to get it running:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize


a = np.linspace(0.2, 2.0, num=1000)
z = 0.5  

def f(P):
    return 1/(z * P**2 + P) - (P**a + P + 1)

res = []
for a in a:
    res.append({'a': a, 'res': optimize.newton(f, 1e-8)})

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 0.2, 'res': 0.00010002999768233757},
 {'a': 0.20180180180180182, 'res': 0.0001000299976875557},
 {'a': 0.2036036036036036, 'res': 0.00010002999769268795},
 {'a': 0.20540540540540542, 'res': 0.00010002999769773575},
 {'a': 0.20720720720720723, 'res': 0.00010002999770270046}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I add to my question a similar code I wrote using the same tools. I can't understand why that works but this doesn't.